# Error in renaming package: "Cannot create file 'com'. File already exist."

Tags: java, android, build, package

The problem is that in the debug folder, the folder is already in the google folder. There is also a folder with the name of my first part of the package. So when I try to rename the first part of the package in my project, I get an error: 
`Cannot create file 'D:\...\...\...\build\generated\source\r\debug\com'. File already exist.` In my other projects, the folder with the name of the first part of the package is built in the folder 'com', and here in the 'debug' itself. Tell me, what can I do? Can I somehow change the build path of this folder in debug?

Comment: What does your code look like? What did you try so far? Just a error message is not that helpful.

Answer (score 9):

1. Go to *Project view* in left pane **-> (project name folder) -> build**
2. There you will get 3 or 4 folders like: generated, intermediate, outputs like this: [image]
3. Select all 3 or 4 folders in that build folder and delete them.
4. Go to *Android view* in left pane and try to refactor your package name
5. After that rebuild your project.

That's it!